# JS/React - How should I use a fetch call inside of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, fetch

I'm still a little unfamiliar with asynchronous functions beyond their simplest forms, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

Some information:

getCollection() returns an array of objects that look like this.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "userId": 3,
  "gameId": 3498,
  "review": "Testing review for game 1"
},
```

getGameById() takes in a integer (the id of a game) and returns that game object from an external API.

gameArray should be getting filled with game objects whose IDs in the external API match the IDs from the array of objects provided by getCollection.

```
const [games, setGames] = useState([])

const getGames = () => {
        getCollection().then(userGames => {
            let gameArray = []
            for (const eachObj of userGames) {
                if (eachObj.userId === currentUserId) {
                    getGameById(eachObj.gameId).then(game => {
                        gameArray.push(game)
                        })
                }
            }
            Promise.all(gameArray).then(() => {
                console.log(gameArray) //logs empty array, but shouldn't be empty
                setGames(gameArray)
            })
        })
    }
```

I have never used Promise.all before, it's just something I saw as a possible solution to this issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises.

First you must build the array of promises. Then you must call `Promise.all` with this array to retrieve all the games :

```
function getGames() {
    getCollection().then(userGames => {
        const gamePromises = userGames
               .filter(userGame => userGame.userId == currenUserId)
               .map(userGame => getGameById(userGame.gameId));

        Promise.all(gamePromises).then(games=> {
            console.log(games);
            setGames(games)
        });
    })
}
```

Here is another solution using [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which is maybe more readable

```
async function getGames() {
  const userGames = await getCollection();
  const currentUserGames = userGames.filter(({userId}) => userId == currentUserId);
  const games = await Promise.all(userGames.map(({gameId}) => getGameById(gameId));
  setGames(games);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's working great. Thank you. I tried making sense of how Promise.all was being used on the existing questions I searched through, but the way you have it written here actually makes sense to me. I don't know why, but a lot of the code I see on this site (even in languages I'm familiar with), looks foreign to me and I struggle to make sense enough of it to replicate on my own, without copy/paste. I would upvote your response but currently I'm about as reputable as an ant lol.

Comment: You must understand that when you do `getGameById(eachObj.gameId).then(game => { gameArray.push(game) })`. The code written inside the `then` is not executed immediately, it will be executed after the api returns a response. So when you reach `Promise.all` in your code, `gameArray` is empty because none of the `gameArray.push` had been executed.

Answer (score 0):

The array that you pass to `Promise.all` needs to contain the promises, but you're pushing the game objects - and you're doing it asynchronously, so the array is still empty when you pass it to `Promise.all`.

```
const getGames = () => {
    getCollection().then(userGames => {
        let gamePromises = []
        for (const eachObj of userGames) {
            if (eachObj.userId === currentUserId) {
                gamePromises.push(getGameById(eachObj.gameId))
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^
            }
        }
        return Promise.all(gamePromises)
//      ^^^^^^ chaining
    }).then(gameArray => {
//          ^^^^^^^^^
        console.log(gameArray)
        setGames(gameArray)
    })
}
```

To simplify:

```
async function getGames() {
    const userGames = await getCollection()
    const gamePromises = userGames
        .filter(eachObj => eachObj.userId === currentUserId)
        .map(eachObj => getGameById(eachObj.gameId))
    const gameArray = await Promise.all(gamePromises)
    console.log(gameArray)
    setGames(gameArray)
}
```

Comment: This worked as well as the first answer posted. You guys basically gave the same solution just written a little differently. Thank you.